# Cut out polygons that at least partially fall in another polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a large polygon shapefile that describes a river catchment. I also have another polygon shapefile that contains a number of smaller polygons that represent districts.

I would like to create a new shapefile, containing only those wards that are at least partially in the large polygon (the river catchment).

I think that clipping will get rid of those parts of the districts outside the river basin. However, I want to retain those parts of the districts that are partially inside the basin.

What function can I use?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using a "select by location" query. You can select all of the smaller polygons that intersect (partially and entirely) with the larger river catchment polygon. Once those selected polygons are highlighted, you can then go to the layer and save the selected features as a new shapefile.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me - as I asked the question, I had found this solution and works perfectly

Comment: If this solution works, please select it as the correct answer so that the question can be closed. Welcome to GIS.SE, and please take the tour https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour